# controller name contain more then two capital letter not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

i have built application using codeigniter,
my controller name is `userReg`, in controller i declared class like this,

```
class UserReg extends CI_Controller { }
```

when i link this controller i used, `<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>userReg">Register</a>`
it works fine in localhost, but when i put online, it's generate page not found error,
i have tried also `<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>userreg">Register</a>`, but doesn't work.
so is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the style guide, you shouldn't use CamelCase by the way:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class_and_method_naming

Comment: link ios broken. could you please update this one. or write what it said exactly. Please

Answer (score 1):

Your development machine is probably windows which has a case insestive file system and you deployed on a case sensitive *nix system.

The first thing to check is make sue the file names of the controllers are all lowercase. That might solve.

Best practice i found is to have classes all lower cased and use _ to separate words.